# MySQL flatten 2 joined recursive tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join, recursion

I have a set of tables that look like the following

```
 equipment
 _____________________________________________________
 equipmentID | name
 _____________________________________________________
       1       widgetA  
       2       widgetB

 group
 _____________________________________________________
 fk_equipmentID | groupId | fk_parentGroupID | label
 _____________________________________________________
       1            1        null          Dimensions
       1            2        1             Overall
       1            3        2             External
       1            4        3             length
       1            5        3             width
       1            6        3             height
       1            7        null          Dimensions
       1            8        7             Overall
       1            9        8             Internal
       1           10        9             length
       1           11        9             width
       1           12        9             height
       1           13        null          color

 valueGroup
 _____________________________________________________
 fk_groupID | valueID | fk_parentVlaueID
 _____________________________________________________
     4          1           null
    null        2            1
    null        3            1
     5          4           null
     6          5           null
     10         6           null
    null        7            6
     11         8           null
     12         9           null
     13        10           null

 values
 _____________________________________________________
 fk_valueID  | id  | value
 _____________________________________________________
     2          1     5in
     3          2     12.7mm
     5          3     1 meter
     6          4     0.5m
     7          5     2in
     8          6     10in
     9          7     .25m
     10         8     blue
```

How can I flatten the tables to get a result to look like like:

```
 equipmentID | name   | labels                                  | value
 _______________________________________________________________________
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Overall, length     5in
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Overall, length     12.7mm
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Overall, width      1 meter
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Overall, height     0.5m
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Internal, length    2in
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Internal, width     10in
     1         widgetA  Dimensions, External, Internal, height    .25m
     1         widgetA  color                                     blue
```

Table Group has 2 foreign keys:

- fk_equipmentID links to equipent.equipmeintID
- fk_parentGroupID links to group.groupID

The same concept follows for valueGroup:

- fk_groupID links to group.groupID
- fk_parentValueId links to valueID

For both group and valueGroup tables entries may or may not have recursive entries.  group table entries will always have at least one valueGroup entry associated the last ancestor of the group; but may have more than one.

I've been looking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161 and was able to get the labels to display correctly but I haven't been able to get further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tables have a maximum number of depth and you can guarantee it will never be exceeded, use the solution of @Wanderer. Otherwise you **need** a stored procedure/function per recursive value, because it *is not possible* to get recursive data with an unknown depth in any other way. To get certain, use google.
So here is how your stored functions could look like:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getRootValueGroup`(childCId INT, `value` BOOLEAN) RETURNS int(11)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE parentCId INT;
    DECLARE currentCId INT;
    SET parentCId = childCId;
    WHILE !(parentCId IS NULL) DO
        SET currentCId = parentCId;
        IF `value` THEN
            SELECT fk_parentGroupID FROM `group` WHERE groupId = currentCId INTO parentCId;
        ELSE
            SELECT fk_parentVlaueID FROM valueGroup WHERE valueID = currentCId INTO parentCId;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN currentCId;
END
```

and

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `getGroupList`(childCId INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE parentCId INT;
    DECLARE currentCId INT;
    DECLARE labels VARCHAR(256);
    DECLARE label VARCHAR(32);
    SET labels = '';
    SET parentCId = childCId;
    WHILE !(parentCId IS NULL) DO
        SET currentCId = parentCId;
        SELECT fk_parentGroupID, g.label FROM `group` g WHERE groupId = currentCId INTO parentCId, label;
        SET labels = CONCAT(label, ', ', labels);
    END WHILE;
    SET labels = TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM labels));
    RETURN labels;
END
```

Then you can simply do a query like this:

```sql
SELECT e.equipmentID as equipmentID, e.name as name, getGroupList(vg.fk_groupID) as labels, v.`value` as `value`
FROM `values` v
JOIN valueGroup vg ON vg.valueID = getRootValueGroup(v.fk_valueID, FALSE)
JOIN `group` g ON g.groupID = getRootValueGroup(vg.fk_groupID, TRUE)
JOIN `equipment` e ON e.equipmentID = g.fk_equipmentID
```

The result would look a bit different from yours:

```
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, External, length|5in
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, External, length|12.7mm
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, External, height|1 meter
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, Internal, length|0.5m
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, Internal, length|2in
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, Internal, width |10in
|1|widgetA|Dimensions, Overall, Internal, height|0.25m
|1|widgetA|color                                |blue
```

But I can't imagine how possibly you would get the result you showed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.equipmentID,name,
 IF(T2.label IS NULL,T1.label,
 CONCAT(T1.label,', ',T2.label,', ',T3.label,', ',T4.label)) as labels,
 v.value
FROM equipment e
INNER JOIN `group` T1 ON T1.fk_equipmentID = e.equipmentID AND T1.fk_parentGroupID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN `group` T2 ON T2.fk_parentGroupID = T1.groupID AND T2.fk_equipmentID = T1.fk_equipmentID
LEFT JOIN `group` T3 ON T3.fk_parentGroupID = T2.groupID AND T3.fk_equipmentID = T1.fk_equipmentID
LEFT JOIN `group` T4 ON T4.fk_parentGroupID = T3.groupID AND T4.fk_equipmentID = T1.fk_equipmentID
INNER JOIN valueGroup vg1 ON (vg1.fk_groupID = T4.groupID) OR (vg1.fk_groupID = T1.groupID)
LEFT JOIN valueGroup vg2 ON (vg2.fk_parentValueID = vg1.valueID)
INNER JOIN `values` v ON (v.fk_valueID = vg1.valueID) OR (v.fk_valueID = vg2.valueID)
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01fcf/23/0)

Comment: Be aware that the 'recursiveness' this query will catch is limited to a specific number of levels (3 for `group`, 1 for `valueGroup`). Whether this is a good solution depends on the required scalability of your database.